# Using operator new on non-pod structs + Initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, initializer-list

I was trying out some stuff allocating structs, which contain non-pod members, on the heap and initializing them using initializer lists. However, the compiler encountered an error on my code. This snippet reproduces it:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    int a;
    std::vector<int> b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> some_vec;
    A a = {1}; // OK
    A b = A{1}; // OK
    A *c = new A{1}; // OK(leaks, NP)
    B d = {1, some_vec}; // OK
    B e = B{1, some_vec}; // OK

    B *f = new B{1, some_vec}; // Fails to compile

    B *g = new B({1, some_vec}); // OK
}
```

(I know that leaks, I'm aware of that, it's just a test snippet)

The line pointed out fails to compile, on GCC 4.6.3, with this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
test.cpp:19:29: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:7:8: note: B::B()
test.cpp:7:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
test.cpp:7:8: note: B::B(const B&)
test.cpp:7:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
test.cpp:7:8: note: B::B(B&&)
test.cpp:7:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Apparently the compiler can't initialize my struct using the provided initializer list. The strange this is that the next line after the one that produces an error, which(at far as I can see) just copies(probably moves) a `B` from another that was constructed using that same initializer list, does not produce any error.

Is there anything wrong I am doing? I mean, I can live using that last line on the snippet provided, but is there any reason why I can't just create a struct using operator new and an initialization list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should compile and work. I tested it with gcc 4.7.0, and it works fine, so the bug has been fixed it seems. If you read 8.5.4 List-initialization in the standard, they say `List intialization can be used as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)`.

Comment: I suspected that it could be a bug in GCC. Thanks for trying it.